# SQL Server query (MAX+COUNT)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-order-by, where-clause

I am currently working on a quick query on Microsoft SQL Server that should return different INSTALLATION that had the MAX amount of EVENTS on the last year.

This is what I got so far but I know that this is not the right way and was hoping for some insight:

```
SELECT 
    i.idInstalac, i.nomInstalac, COUNT(e.idEvento) as cantEventos    
FROM
    Instalacion i, Eventos e    
WHERE 
    i.idInstalac = e.idInstalac 
    AND YEAR(e.fchEvento) = 2019   
GROUP BY 
    i.idInstalac, i.nomInstalac
HAVING 
    MAX cantEventos
```

Thanks

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is `TOP (1) WITH TIES`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES i.idInstalac, i.nomInstalac, COUNT(e.idEvento) as cantEventos 
FROM Instalacion i
INNER JOIN Eventos e ON i.idInstalac = e.idInstalac 
WHERE e.fchEvento >= '2019-01-01' and e.fchEvento < '2020-01-01'
GROUP BY i.idInstalac,i.nomInstalac 
ORDER BY cantEventos DESC
```

Note that I rewrote your implicit `JOIN` as an explicit, modern join (with the `ON` keyword): implicit join is an old syntax that should not be used in new code. I also changed the date filter in the `WHERE` clause: using date functions on the column is less efficient, and prevents the database from using an existing index

Comment: Thanks for the quick follow up. Sorry I was just finishing editing the initial post as it was kind of clustered (kind of new posting questions).
I understand using TOP but this one particular should bring all the cases where the different facilities had the same amount of events if there were 2 or more that had the same amount

Comment: Not familiar with the "WITH TIES" and perhaps that was the thing I was missing

Comment: @juanmaperez: yes, that's what `WITH TIES` does.

Comment: Think that this might be what I was looking for with the TIES format and also thanks for the insight with the different changes I will be marking this as answered as soon as I can.